# Custom UITableViewCell that looks like the standard cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to create a custom UITableViewCell with the goal that it should look and resize exactly the same way as the standard cell. The only difference is that my custom cell is using an editable UITextField instead of a UILabel.

It is working fine except for the case when dynamic type is set to smaller than default.

Here's the setup:

[image]

Here's how it looks in three different dynamic text sizes:

[image]

The one on the very right is the problem. Here my cell on the top is much smaller than the default cell with the "Login" label below it.

How can I make my cell have the exact same size as the default cell in all dynamic text sizes?

Comment: Why do you want it to have the same size? The UI would break for larger fonts. Your text will spill outside the view. That is very bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `textField` in a simple view, let's call it `wrapperView` that has top, bottom, leading and trailing constraint to the `contentView` set to 0; then on your `wrapperView` set an height constraint that is `greaterThanOrEqualTo` a minimum value, i.e 44pt (which should be the default cell height)

Comment: He says he wants it to have the same size for all text sizes.

Comment: He said that the problem is in the right image, which has a cell smaller than the default size, which is 44; for example in the center image the Login cell is greater that 44 and it's ok

Comment: Read the last line of the question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys. @RicoCrescenzio you got me right, that's exactly what I wanted. Great idea with the minimum size, I did it with a smaller value directly on the UITextField without the wrapper view though.